# How to make Gnuplot visible in Octave on Windows?

Tags: cygwin, gnuplot, octave

?I have installed Cygwin64 on Windows 7 with the following packages:  `octave` (version 3.8.2), `xterm`, `xinit`, `xlaunch`, `gnuplot`. However, when typing `figure;` in the `Cygwin Terminal` window, no `Gnuplot` graphical window appear, instead the figure is plotted inside the `Cygwin Terminal` window.

What is wrong in my setup, or in my expectations. How do I get `Gnuplot` visible?
Thanks in advance !